# SimpleDateFormat vs ZonedDateTime with timezone

Tags: java, java-8, simpledateformat, java-time

I'm trying to convert PST timestamp to epoch time.

The first method I tried is using zoned datetime by passing America/Los Angeles as input time zone.

```
    public static void changeStringDateFormatToEpoch(String oldDate, String format) throws ParseException {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(oldDate, dtf);
        ZonedDateTime zdtzone = dt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
        System.out.println("When date: "+ oldDate + " is in format "+ format + " --> "  + zdtzone.toEpochSecond());
    }
```

After this I tried running the below code which uses SimpleDateFormat to do the same

```
 public static void changeStringDateFormatToEpochSimpleDate(String oldDate, String format) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date dt = sdf.parse(oldDate);
        long epoch = dt. getTime();
        System.out.println("When date: "+ oldDate + " is in format "+ format + " --> "  + epoch);
    }
```

How is that both the outputs are similar, when in the 2nd case I'm not even specifying the timezone of the input date.

Shouldn't the epoch time get affected since the input time zone is PST(America/Los Angeles)?

*sample input*

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date = "2019-11-27 04:32:41.000-0800"; //yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
        String date2 = "2019-11-27 04:32:41"; // yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss


        try {
            changeStringDateFormatToEpoch(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
            changeStringDateFormatToEpoch(date2, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            changeStringDateFormatToEpochSimpleDate(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
            changeStringDateFormatToEpochSimpleDate(date2, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void changeStringDateFormatToEpoch(String oldDate, String format) throws ParseException {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(oldDate, dtf);
        ZonedDateTime zdtzone = dt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
        System.out.println("When date: "+ oldDate + " is in format "+ format + " --> "  + zdtzone.toEpochSecond());
    }

    public static void changeStringDateFormatToEpochSimpleDate(String oldDate, String format) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date dt = sdf.parse(oldDate);
        long epoch = dt. getTime();
        System.out.println("SimpleDate : When date: "+ oldDate + " is in format "+ format + " --> "  + epoch);
    }
}
```

*output*

```
When date: 2019-11-27 04:32:41.000-0800 is in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ --> 1574857961
When date: 2019-11-27 04:32:41 is in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss --> 1574857961
SimpleDate : When date: 2019-11-27 04:32:41.000-0800 is in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ --> 1574857961000
SimpleDate : When date: 2019-11-27 04:32:41 is in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss --> 1574857961000
```

Comment: What `format` value are you passing to those 2 methods? What is the default time zone of the JVM? Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g. instead of just showing `String date2 = "2019-11-27 04:32:41";`, show us the actual call `changeStringDateFormatToEpoch("2019-11-27 04:32:41", "...")` and the output you get with that.

Comment: You can't parse `"2019-11-27 04:32:41"` to a `ZonedDateTime`, so your question makes no sense.

Comment: I've added the sample function call and output I got.
@OleV.V.  I'm based in PST. Is that the reason why its getting converted to the correct epoch time without specifying the timezone?

Comment: @Andreas Can you please explain why ZonedDateTime cannot parse?

Comment: @MhnCodes I think the error message says it all: `ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-11-27 04:32:41", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))` throws *DateTimeException: **Unable to obtain ZoneId***, because there is no time zone specified in the input string, and `ZonedDateTime` requires a time zone (hence the name). --- I copy/pasted the code from the question *as-is*, with the method calls, and I get that error. You failed to provide a ***reproducible*** example for your output.

Comment: @Andreas I have added the reproducible example.
Also please note that, I'm setting the LocalDateTime.atZone before assigning it to ZonedDateTime.

Comment: @Andreas please import `import java.time.ZoneId;` to obtain **ZoneId**

Comment: @MhnCodes *"Unable to obtain ZoneId"* is a description from the Exception at ***run time***, not a compilation error to be fixed with an `import`.

Comment: @MhnCodes So you now want us to use the **second** version of the `changeStringDateFormatToEpoch` method in your question, the one using `LocalDateTime.parse()`, and we should ignore the first part of the question with the version using `ZonedDateTime.parse()`? If so, what is that bad first version still doing in the question? Seems we've been having trouble with your question from the beginning (and still do) because **you posted the wrong code**.

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting. I'm able to run the program without any exception.

Comment: Not if you use the version of `changeStringDateFormatToEpoch` in the first block of code, which calls `ZonedDateTime.parse()`. You know, the **only** version of the method that existed in the question *until 11 minutes ago*, i.e. for the first 1 hour and 10 minutes of the questions existence!!!

Comment: I apoligize for that code. I was trying to optimize my ZonedDateTime function by removing the LocalDateTime.parse. But it doesn't work like you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SimpleDateFormat`-based code works as expected only because you are running it on machine in the Pacific time zone. `SimpleDateFormat` instances are initialized with the system default time zone, but it can be changed.

To make your code robust and portable, use the first approach. Parse a `LocalDateTime`, and then combine it with an explicit `ZoneId`, rather than inferring the default time zone.

Some of the date times parsed in your example use an offset date-time. This is helpful; many developers in zones afflicted by daylight-saving time overlook the need to include some indication whether daylight saving is currently in effect when storing local time stamps. Without it, there is ambiguity in parsing times during the autumn transition to standard time.

In any case, you should be aware that it is also possible to combine a `LocalDateTime` with a `ZoneOffset` to produce an `OffsetDateTime`, and from that, an epoch time.

Answer (score 0):

After editing your `changeStringDateFormatToEpoch()` has a new problem: it is now ignoring the offset `-0800` given in the string. As long as it happens to agree with the time zone you provide hardcoded in the code, the result is OK; but if the offset had been different, you would have obtained an incorrect result. Even for America/Los_Angeles time zone you will get an incorrect result at the overlap when summer time (DST) ends, clock times are repeated and the offset is your only chance of distinguishing.

The code using `SimpleDateFormat` can be said to have the opposite problem: in case of an absent time zone or offset it uses the JVM’s default time zone, which may or may not be the intended. Chances are further harmed by the fact that the JVM time zone setting can be changed at any time by another part of your program or another program running in the same JVM.

If you know that America/Los Angeles time zone will be intended for strings without zone or offset, the solution is this variant:

```
/** @throws DateTimeParseException if oldDate is not in the format given */
public static void changeStringDateFormatToEpoch(String oldDate, String format) {
    // Time zone to use if neither time zone nor UTC offset is given in the string
    ZoneId defaultZone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
    DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withZone(defaultZone);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(oldDate, dtf);
    System.out.println("When date: " + oldDate + " is in format " + format
                        + " --> "  + zdt.toEpochSecond());
}
```

Let’s try it out using your own code:

```
    String date = "2019-11-27 04:32:41.000-0800"; //yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
    String date2 = "2019-11-27 04:32:41"; // yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

    changeStringDateFormatToEpoch(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    changeStringDateFormatToEpoch(date2, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Even when running in my time zone, Europe/Copenhagen, the results agree:

> ```
> When date: 2019-11-27 04:32:41.000-0800 is in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ --> 1574857961
> When date: 2019-11-27 04:32:41 is in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss --> 1574857961
> ```

**To answer your questions**

> How is that both the outputs are similar, when in the 2nd case I'm not
>   even specifying the timezone of the input date.

In the second case `SimpleDateFormat` uses the time zone setting of your JVM. Only because this is America/Los_Angeles (or another time zone that uses offset -08:00 on November 27) do the outputs agree. When running in a different time zone they would not.

> Shouldn't the epoch time get affected since the input time zone is
>   PST(America/Los Angeles)?

The output is affected by the JVM’s default time zone. It doesn’t use UTC or some other default unless the default is set so.

**Do not use `SimpleDateFormat`**

The `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. It’s somehow not surprising that it gives you a surprising result. Do use java.time, the modern Java date and time API that `ZonedDateTime` is a part of for your date and time work. It tends to give a lot fewer surprises and more natural code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Hong_Kong"));
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy - hh:mm:ss zzz");
    String formattedString = zonedDateTime.format(dateTimeFormatter);
    System.out.println(String.format("ZonedDateTime [%s], Formatted ZonedDateTime [%s]", zonedDateTime, formattedString));
```

output is - ZonedDateTime [2022-03-17T17:09:27.471+08:00[Asia/Hong_Kong]], Formatted ZonedDateTime [03/17/2022 - 05:09:27 HKT]

but when i do

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy - hh:mm:ss zzz");
    String format = simpleDateFormat.format(zonedDateTime);
    System.out.println(format);
```

throw error

Cannot format given Object as a Date

Which means SimpleDateFormat is not support ZonedDateTime  ?